# How to check if view is already on top

Tags: android

I want to check if a particular `view` is on the top or not, and if is not on top, then I want to bring it to the top.

I used `bringToFront()`, which gets it on top but before that I want to check if its already on top.

Is there any way to know the index of a particular `view`.

Comment: Have you tried `indexOfChild(View child)` ? It returns the position in the group of the specified child view.

Comment: I want to check if its already on top.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ViewGroup.indexOfChild(View child)` method. It returns a positive integer representing the position of the view in the group, or -1 if the view does not exist in the group.